# Imprimir pagina HTML em navegadores mobile

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou construindo um sistema que vai funcionar na web em PHP, onde tenho que realizar algumas impressões de alguns comprovantes. O sistema consegue imprimir as páginas em HTML quando eu estou no computador, quando estou acessando o sistema por um Smartfone ou tablet a função de imprimir não funciona. O botão aparece, mostra que é clicado, porem nada acontece.
O comando que estou usando é este:

```html
<a onclick="window.print()" class="btn btn-primary no-print">Imprimir</a>
```

Minha duvida é se essa função de imprimir é genérica, ou existe uma específica para os dispositivos mobiles.

Comment: tentei executar o `window.print()` usando a versão `46.0.2490.76` do Chrome para Android, e a tela de impressão apareceu normalmente. porém dependendo da sua versão do Navegador, será preciso usar o [Google Cloud Print](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/devguide), quanto ao iOS, acredito que o mesmo já dá suporte ao `windows.print()` já a um bom tempo, porém desconheço a quantas vai o WP neste sentido.

Comment: A minha resposta não foi válida @JoséAllison. Se não, como posso melhora-la?

Comment: Vou testar e te dou uma resposta @Danilo.

Comment: Ok. Fico no aguardo...

Comment: @Danilo. Funciona em alguns dispositivos, pelo que eu pude notar, em dispositivos Android de versão 4.3+. =/

Comment: Só nas versões superiores a 4.3 do android? Não entendi muito bem.

Comment: @TobyMosque. A versão do meu google chrome é essa e não funciona. Atualizei pra uma versão mais a frente e também não funcionou. Não sei se tem alguma coisa haver com a versão do Android =/

Comment: Isso @Danilo. Estou realizando testes aqui em um tablet e em um celular, ambos na versão 4.3. Em versões superiores a essa (Testei em um MotoG de versão 5.0) e funcionou normalmente.

Answer (score 1):

Pode-se colocar no proprio href

```
<a href="javascript: window.print();" class="btn btn-primary no-print">Imprimir</a>
```

JSFIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/0t27oovt/